# .Net Core 2.0 to 2.1: 'IMutableEntityType' does not contain a definition for 'Scaffolding'

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, .net-core-2.1

We have a .Net Core 2.0 API using a psql database.
When updating to .Net Core 2.1, it stopped building and returned the following error:

```
'IMutableEntityType' does not contain a definition for 'Scaffolding' and no extension method 'Scaffolding' accepting a first argument of type 'IMutableEntityType' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

This extension methods was not intended for external use, but we need it to change entities schema at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

It's a one liner, but it took me some time to find that I had to change

```
builder.Entity(type).Metadata.Scaffolding();
```

to

```
builder.Entity(type).Metadata.Relational();
```

I hope it can help someone.